# Smack android roster not refreshing

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

1.6 and I'm trying to get to list of users connected it works fine but it always keep showing the same list of users even when they are offline . I mean the list is not refreshing even when I reinstall the app it keep showing the same users even if none of them is connected

this  is my code , thanks

```
Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);

            if (!roster.isLoaded())
                try { Log.e("Waiting========>", "starts");
                    roster.reloadAndWait();

                } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            Log.e("Waiting========>", "stops");
            roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                Log.e("Entry=======>", entry.getUser().toString());
              //  destination=entry.toString();


            }
```

Comment: That sounds like the expected behavior. Roster Items only change when you add it remove them. Are you sure that you don't confuse this with the presence status?

Comment: And what do you mean with '1.6'?

Comment: it was a mistyping fault  I meant I'm using smack 4.1.6

Comment: @Flow I am not able to refresh my roster's presence after reconnecting. I am getting all my rosters unavailable. How do I able to solve this?